# compile a package with alle changed Java classes

Tags: java, version-control

I have build a set of Java classes that act as kind of plugins in a third party application. 
When ever new request come on my table I create new classes (plugins) or modify existing one.
To make the changes available to the third party application I can put a Jar into an so called extlib directory or put single class files into an so called ext directory.

I am looking for a proper way to handle different versions of my files.
When changing only one single class it a bad idea to replace all class files in ext dir. Same problem when compiling as JAR. After changing one single class, I would have to compile q whole new JAR with all files inside.
Replacing all files inherits the chance of accidentely replacing a untested change.

Do you have any hints / best practices of how I could manage the different file versions?

My Ideas:
Some kind of patch would be great. When changing some files, I just push a button to compile a zip archive with all changed files inside. In optimal case with a version mark in all the files.
Would something like this be possible with eclipse plugins pxe.?

Comment: Extdir is deprecated. Don't use that mechanusm.

Comment: This looks like an entire school of [red herrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) to me.  It seems like all you want is a mechanism for ensuring that a software release only includes files that have been properly tested and does not include files that have not been tested yet.  Is that right?

Comment: To be honest, your are right.

BUT to ensure this, I do not want to test the whole set of classes. (I would have to when delivering them) so I want to deliver only the files really changed for the corresponding change request / bug / issue

Answer (score 0):

There exist a number of workflows for this.

The terminology varies a bit depending on the version control system that you are using; I am going to use git terminology.

One workflow is to always work on a branch, and to never merge a branch that has not been thoroughly tested into master.  So, then, a release is only made from master.

Another workflow is to work on whatever branch you want, merge into master whenever you want, then every once in a while pull from master into a designated "release" workspace, do your testing there, and then release from that.

As for binary patching, I am sure there exist tools out there, but I do not know of one, I asked a few people and they don't know either, so I have no answer for you here.  I suppose if you have `.class` files you can use some folder synchronization tool, but if you have `.jar` files then you are going to be replacing them in their entirety.